# PHP CURL Proxy not working

Tags: curl, proxy

I am trying from a day but PHP CURL Proxy not working (gives blank page) as following setting

- I had use code on shared hostgator
- CURL working fine but on Proxy code its not working
- I had tried using various code of file_get_contents and CURL but still not working

**code 1**

```
$url = 'http://websiteurl.com';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE,CURLPROXY_HTTP);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_PROXY,'proxyhost:port');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);   
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,120);   
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

**code 2**

```
$ch = curl_init($url);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);           
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "proxyhost:port");  
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

**code 3**

```
$ch = curl_init();   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1");  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'proxyhost:port');  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, '8800');    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
curl_exec($ch); 
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

**None of above code working, just give blank page.**

**Also somebody know what may be the problem(s)!!!**

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: I figure it out as my proxy server ip was not working, using some other proxy i fount its work... but need to explore more as it only works with port 80

Comment: SOLVE: My hosting provider had black listed proxys as its worked only for some proxy specified at server level..... So if you got this problem please your server is enabled proxy from all port.